# OperationalError: no such column: None

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I get the error message: OperationalError: no such column: None when I try to run the code below. The error is because the SQLite row iterator gives me back a 'None' where the null value is when I do the str(row).

I could do a replace on the string and replace , None , with , Null ,   I guess but was wondering if there's a better solution?

```
for row in c.execute(sqlStr):
    tmp = str(row)[:-1] +', ' + str(rowCount) + ')'
    insertStr = 'Insert into  tblMain (userID, PlayedTimeStamp, TimeSinceFirstPlay,ArtistID, ArtistName, TrackID, TrackName,historyID) Values ' + tmp
    c.execute(insertStr)
```

Comment: Not the answer but I think you forget `(` after values

Answer (score 0):

You're buidling and executing the statement with each loop iteration, but I guess what you want is gathering the data to insert first (in `tmp`), then concatenating it to the statement. Therefore you list 8 columns to insert data into, but provide only two with each loop iteration. What's more, your snippet doesn't show where `rowCount` comes from, and I guess it's not defined and thus replaced with "None" when trying to convert it to a string.

Alltogether the code is quite ugly and a bit obfuscated; I suggest to clean it up and use `print` statements to debug the actual content of your query.